# RewriteRule hides folder from URLs, somehow Google is indexing the true path

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm removing a folder from my files path (/files/) and it's working on the site just fine.  When I look at any page's source I don't see the folder name anywhere and it's not in any sitemaps.  Somehow "The Google" is finding the true path and those are showing up in the 'Not Found' section of google webmaster tools.

**Basically I have images/PDFs on the server in a path like:**
doc_root/files/manufacture/category/subcat/

**The HTML to my images/PDFs look like:**

domain.com/manufacture/category/subcat/image.jpg
or
domain.com/manufacture/category/subcat/part.pdf

**I’m using this in my .htaccess to remove the /files/ folder from that path:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!files/).*)$ files//$1 [L,NC]
```

I think I cound dissalow that files directory in my robots.txt to keep that from happening .... but I'm really more curious as to how they found it in the first place.

Comment: If google ever did see them in the past google will keep trying. I've had pages or folders removed from sites for several years and they will still try. In Google webmaster tools you can request the removal of specific urls but  it takes time

Comment: Yea I've ran into that before too.  This is a new folder I made to clean up the files on the server and it was not live before that rule was in place.  Whatever they found that list is growing very fast.

Comment: Is there anywhere else you may have linked to using the structure that you don't want and google has found through those links?

Comment: I can't find it anyplace.....

Comment: Another possibility is if you opened that path in browser I know IE / Bing has been known to send on visited urls to be indexed and wouldn't be surprised if Chrome / Google did similar

Comment: Good thought, I've had my IP filtered out in Analytics way before this started.  I would hope Google wouldn't grab what I test anyway, if they did I'd think they'd have all kinda of other odd links.